# Fast hashing algorithm that does not produce collision in large datasets

Tags: postgresql, hash

I have a dataset of potentially a few billion strings of different lengths that I need to run an expensive analysis on. Essentially I just need to compute a hard to compute value for each of them. Since we often have system restart, which would need to recalculate essentially everything from scratch, I would like to create a caching system using a simple key value database that just maps a hash to a calculated value, using the hash as a primary key.
I thought about using murmur hash but I read there was no guarantee that there would be no collisions in a sufficiently large dataset. And something like Sha256 would obviously be complete and total overkill for something like this (meaning too slow). So is there some other algorithm in between that I could use for this? Bonus points if its natively supported by PostgreSQL.

Comment: Any hash will involve the chance of collision. If you have 257 unique values and an 8 bit hash then it is inevitable.

Comment: not true. There has never been a sha256 hash discovered

Comment: You cannot create a collision on demand but if your range of domain values is bigger than your range of hash values then it is an inevitability.

Comment: yes but murmur hash needs only a hundred million records to have a high chance to produce a collision. Sha256 needs something like 2 to the power of 200

Comment: If you're asking for a guarantee then you're out of luck, there is no guarantee, even with sha256 or even sha512. There are only sufficiently low probabilities. And that's where you need to do your homework. You need to come up with an acceptable probability of collision or some related figure. After you choose this parameter then the appropriate hash function can be selected. However, I don't see why you can't use a *standard* hash table that includes a scheme for handling collisions, rather than an exotic hash algorithm that must be collision-free.